# получить данные из сложного словаря на Python

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, как получить значения из словаря имея только значение соседнего ключа, пример:

Есть словарь из словарей. У меня есть значение {C079BF5C-AE8B-C3B8-225C-B577A745B92B}, мне нужно получить значения полей name и phone

```
"7":{
            "UID":"{C079BF5C-AE8B-C3B8-225C-B577A745B92B}",
            "isgroup":"0",
            "parentid":"{75CA33FD-7127-5092-BEDF-F4597D6F7F1D}",
            "idlink":"NULL",
            "idout":"00000004",
            "name":"Канат Китай пакет Алматы",
            "fullname":"NULL",
            "shtrih":"NULL",
            "birthday":"2023-04-04",
            "email":"NULL",
            "phone":"+7702968xxxx",
            "marketing_src":0,
            "rnn":"NULL",
            "iikbank":"NULL",
            "beneficiary_bank":"NULL",
            "BIK":"NULL",
            "address":"NULL",
            "details":"NULL",
            "info":"NULL",
            "dtedit":"2023-08-06 11:27:19"
         },
"8":{
            "UID":"{DC121B98-E087-36EA-8617-5D70CF43DF9A}",
            "isgroup":"0",
            "parentid":"{75CA33FD-7127-5092-BEDF-F4597D6F7F1D}",
            "idlink":"NULL",
            "idout":"00000005",
            "name":"Нуржан посуда А (Ернат)",
            "fullname":"NULL",
            "shtrih":"NULL",
            "birthday":"2023-04-06",
            "email":"NULL",
            "phone":"+7707555xxxx",
            "marketing_src":0,
            "rnn":"NULL",
            "iikbank":"NULL",
            "beneficiary_bank":"NULL",
            "BIK":"NULL",
            "address":"NULL",
            "details":"NULL",
            "info":"NULL",
            "dtedit":"2023-08-06 11:27:19"
         },
```

Comment: Никак.  (Только перебрать все элементы списка.)  Если запросы частые,  используйте другой контейнер для хранения данных.

Comment: Ммм… первое что приходит в голову — идти по всем значениям, выцеплять UID и делать связку с ключом родительского элемента. А потом по вашим значениям брать этот ключ и внутри что вам необходимо.

Comment: Можно ещё в датафрейм в `pandas` запихнуть, структура позволяет, скушает быстро скорее всего.

Comment: извиняюсь! Ошибка - не список из словарей, а словарь из словарей

Comment: разницы не будет. Все равно надо будет пробежаться по всем членам словаря (в наихудшем исходе), если использовать простой перебор. Вопрос надо решать либо оптимизацией поиска, либо подниматься на уровень выше и обрабатывать основной словарь до обращения к определенной записи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
j='''{
"7":{
            "UID":"{C079BF5C-AE8B-C3B8-225C-B577A745B92B}",
            "isgroup":"0",
            "parentid":"{75CA33FD-7127-5092-BEDF-F4597D6F7F1D}",
            "idlink":"NULL",
            "idout":"00000004",
            "name":"Канат Китай пакет Алматы",
            "fullname":"NULL",
            "shtrih":"NULL",
            "birthday":"2023-04-04",
            "email":"NULL",
            "phone":"+7702968xxxx",
            "marketing_src":0,
            "rnn":"NULL",
            "iikbank":"NULL",
            "beneficiary_bank":"NULL",
            "BIK":"NULL",
            "address":"NULL",
            "details":"NULL",
            "info":"NULL",
            "dtedit":"2023-08-06 11:27:19"
         },
"8":{
            "UID":"{DC121B98-E087-36EA-8617-5D70CF43DF9A}",
            "isgroup":"0",
            "parentid":"{75CA33FD-7127-5092-BEDF-F4597D6F7F1D}",
            "idlink":"NULL",
            "idout":"00000005",
            "name":"Нуржан посуда А (Ернат)",
            "fullname":"NULL",
            "shtrih":"NULL",
            "birthday":"2023-04-06",
            "email":"NULL",
            "phone":"+7707555xxxx",
            "marketing_src":0,
            "rnn":"NULL",
            "iikbank":"NULL",
            "beneficiary_bank":"NULL",
            "BIK":"NULL",
            "address":"NULL",
            "details":"NULL",
            "info":"NULL",
            "dtedit":"2023-08-06 11:27:19"
         }}'''
s=json.loads(j)
for el in s:
    if s[el]["UID"]=="{C079BF5C-AE8B-C3B8-225C-B577A745B92B}":
        print(s[el]["name"])
        print(s[el]["phone"])
```

---

```
Канат Китай пакет Алматы
+7702968xxxx
```

Comment: Да, именно так и получилось у меня :-) БлагоДарю!